# How to sort map with multiple dates as values in java

Tags: java, collections

How to sort HashMap entries by multiple values as dates

Suppose I have a map with key String and value as Object with 2 dates.

Sorting to be done by both dates in the object

```
Map<String, dateWrapper> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("user10",new dateWrapper("20180131","20181231"));    
map.put("user3",new dateWrapper("20170131","20171231")); 
map.put("user5",new dateWrapper("20160131","20161231")); 
map.put("user1",new dateWrapper("20170131","20170131"));
```

** NOTE : above strings are parsed as dates by using SimpleDateFormat

Expected out put is user5,user1,user3,user10

public class dateWrapper implements Serializable {

```
private Date date1;
private Date date2;

}
List<Map.Entry<String, dateWrapper>> dateWrapperEntries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
Trying below  this but its returning null 
Collections.sort(dateWrapperEntries, Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(dateWrapper::getDate1).thenComparing(dateWrapper::getDate2)));

private static Date convertStringToDate(String inputStr) {
    Date inputDate = null;
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    try {
        inputDate = sdf.parse(inputStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inputDate;
}
```

Comment: *its returning null* The return type of Collections.sort() is void. It can't possibly return null. Tell precisely what the problem is, i.e. what the actual output is.

Comment: This snippet produces a correctly sorted list. Can you elaborate what exactly is the issue you're facing?

Comment: when i print  dateWrapperEntries , just printed as []

Comment: That means your map is empty.

Comment: but i could see data in my input map and dateWrapperEntries is not having any sorted list data

Comment: thank you guys its working and yes map is null and it my bad assignment is wrong

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome, and both it and `Date` are long outdated. So avoid using them. Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE` for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<String> sort(Map<String, dateWrapper> map) {
    // comparator to compare two dateWrapper from Map.Entry value
    final Comparator<Map.Entry<String, dateWrapper>> comparator =
            Comparator.comparing((Function<Map.Entry<String, dateWrapper>, Date>)e -> e.getValue().getDate1())
                      .thenComparing(e -> e.getValue().getDate2());

    // convert map to entry set and compare it
    return Optional.ofNullable(map).orElse(Collections.emptyMap()).entrySet().stream()
                   .sorted(comparator)
                   .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: its not long and its date so used Comparator.comparing

Comment: Actually `Date` is `long` :-)

Comment: Date.getTime() is long, @balaji

Comment: Thank you guys its working and yes map is null and it my bad assignment is wrong

Comment: I have added `Optional` to not throw NPE when map is null